# How can i dynamically allocate memory for a array of pointers in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic

I need to allocate memory dynamically for an array of pointers.

Let us assume,

```
char *names[50];
char *element;
```

I used the following code to allocate memory dynamically which is producing error.

```
names=malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

Afterwards, i need  to assign another character pointer to this one, say

```
names=element;
```

I am getting error as `": warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"`.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> names=malloc(sizeof(char *));

Will allocate either 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your system). This doesn't make sense since your array was already sized at 50 entries in the declaration...

> names=element;

This is not how arrays are used in C. You have declared that there are 50 elements in "names" and each one is allocated as a different pointer to an array of characters. You need to decide which element in the array you want to assign. For eaxample:

```
char *test1 = "test string 1";
char *test2 = "test string 2";

names[0] = test1; // Assign pointer to string 1 to first element of array
names[1] = test2; // Assign pointer to string 2 to second element of array
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically allocate an array of `N` `char *`pointers, then you would use:

```
char **names;

names = malloc(N * sizeof p[0]);
```

To assign the `char *` value `element` to the first element in the array, you would then use:

```
names[0] = element;
```

Comment: Correct.  To clarify: your code to dynamically allocate "*names[50]" like "char **names = malloc (sizeof (char) * 50);".  At this point, you would have space for 50 pointers ... and then you would ALSO need to allocate space for the 50 strings (separately!).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this tutorial out:
http://dystopiancode.blogspot.com/2011/10/dynamic-multidimensional-arrays-in-c.html
It says how to allocate dynamic memory for arrays,matrices,cubes and hypercube and also how you can free it.